# Lightbox jQuery

Tags: jquery, javascript, lightbox

Помогите разобраться с Lightbox. На локалке все работает корректно, на хостинге какая то печаль.
вот [ссылка](http://test3.madowl.com.ua/gallery), где можно посмотреть

В хроме пишет

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'lightBox'    gallery:75
(anonymous function)                                             gallery:75
jQuery.fn.extend.ready                                           jquery.js:28
jQuery.extend.ready.jQuery.readyList                             jquery.js:28
jQuery.extend.each                                               jquery.js:22
jQuery.extend.ready
```

Как это исправить? А главное, почему один и тот же проект по разному работает на локалке и на хостинге?

Comment: Отладчик говорит, что:
$("#gallery a").lightBox is not a function

Будто не правильно объявил библиотеку, хотя объявлено вроди верно

Comment: да вот и я смотрю, голову ломаю

Comment: Попробуйте код, который инициализирует галерею обернуть в noConflict - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/
Была похожая проблема, только с каруселью

Comment: не помогает(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

firebug выдаёт ошибку 
TypeError: $("#gallery a").lightBox is not a function
Значит скорее всего

- неправильно подключены или совсем не
     подключены js файлы где описывается
     lightBox
- на хостинге другие js файлы
     чем локально. Размеры файлов (gallery , jquery.js и.т.д) идентичны?
- какой либо блок подгружается раньше
     чем другой. Попробовать обернуть вызов lightBox в функцию $(document).ready

  $(document).ready(function()
  {
  $("#gallery a").lightBox
  ...
  };

Comment: 1. файлы подключены
2. файлы одинаковые
3. обернул, безрезультатно

Comment: Пробовали в самом документе jquery.lightbox-0.5.js

Поставить alert(1); в самом начале и конце страницы?

Возможно сервер возвращает битый js файл.

Comment: поставил два алерта, было два вывода этой единички

Answer (score 1):

> The only necessity is to have a HTML
> markup likes it:

```
<a href="image1.jpg"><img src="thumb_image1.jpg" width="72" height="72" alt="" /></a>
```

Обратите внимание на `thumb_` префикс!!!

Comment: а чем префикс не угодил? все верно, картинки показывает thumb ссылка ведет на большую картинку

Comment: разные картинки должны быть.

Comment: они и так разные

Answer (score 0):

Был какой то баг с самим файлом jquery.lightbox-0.5.js

Заменил его на jquery.lightbox-0.5.min.js все работает